# Replication when changing the subscription field

Tags: replication, sybase, subscription

I'm tring to understand a problem we have on replication but I cannot find a definitive explaination when it comes to the subscription.

Lets say I have a table, 'T' [label, name] and we create a subscription for replication, " where label = 'XX' "

Now I insert into T values ('XX', 'exes') and this will replicate to my other database.

Then if I run; update T set label = 'YY' where label = 'XX'

Will the update be replicated because the orginal record's label matches the subscription? Or will it be filtered from replication because the new label does not match the subscription?

Thanks